# VBA code to consolidate data in one row from three rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have access data for all card numbers. Each card number have 3 entries in three rows. But I want data for each card number in one row.

[image]

I have tried below code but output have 2 lines blank.
[image]

Could you please suggest any alternate solution to get correct data in one row for every card number.

```
Sub ConsolidateData()

    For i = 2 To 19
    
    'for first row
    Sheet3.Range("A" & i) = Sheet2.Range("A" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("B" & i) = Sheet2.Range("B" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("C" & i) = Sheet2.Range("C" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("D" & i) = Sheet2.Range("D" & i)
    
    'for second row
    i = i + 1
    Sheet3.Range("E" & i - 1) = Sheet2.Range("B" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("F" & i - 1) = Sheet2.Range("C" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("G" & i - 1) = Sheet2.Range("D" & i)
    
    'for 3rd row
    i = i + 1
    Sheet3.Range("H" & i - 2) = Sheet2.Range("B" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("I" & i - 2) = Sheet2.Range("C" & i)
    Sheet3.Range("J" & i - 2) = Sheet2.Range("D" & i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: So, the data to be processed are always contained in three consecutive rows. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If the answer of my above question is yes, please test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: Yes, the data to be processed are always contained in three consecutive rows. Thanks!! Your code is working perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and it is very fast (working in memory) and returnS the processed result in the range "A2:J" last necessary row of the next sheet. It can return wherever you need:

```
Sub extractCardData()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet (Sheet2)
   Set sh3 = sh.Next    'the following sheet. Use here your Sheet3, if not the next...
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).value
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) / 3, 1 To 10) 'redim the array to keep the processing result
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr) Step 3                 'iterate between the array elemts from 3 to 3
        k = k + 1                                          'increment the array row
        'put the values in the array columns
        arrFin(k, 1) = arr(i, 1): arrFin(k, 2) = arr(i, 2): arrFin(k, 3) = arr(i, 3): arrFin(k, 4) = arr(i, 4)
        arrFin(k, 5) = arr(i + 1, 2): arrFin(k, 6) = arr(i + 1, 3): arrFin(k, 7) = arr(i + 1, 4)
        arrFin(k, 8) = arr(i + 2, 2): arrFin(k, 9) = arr(i + 2, 3): arrFin(k, 10) = arr(i + 2, 4)
   Next i
   'drop the arrFin content, at once:
   sh3.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 10).value = arrFin
   'format the columns keeping hours:minutes:
   Union(sh3.Range("C2:C" & 2 + UBound(arrFin)), sh3.Range("F2:F" & 2 + UBound(arrFin)), sh3.Range("I2:I" & 2 + UBound(arrFin))).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Card number", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Time", Time.Type}, {"Action", type text}}),

//Unpivot other than the CardNumber so as to have a separate row for each attribute and cardNumber
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Card number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Create our new column headers
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "colHeaders", 
        each [Attribute] & Text.From(Number.Mod(Number.IntegerDivide([Index],3),3)+1)),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Attribute"}),

//Pivot on the created column headers column
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[colHeaders]), "colHeaders", "Value"),

//Sort back to the original row order
//This line is optional
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{each List.PositionOf(List.Distinct(Source[Card number]),[Card number])}  )
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]